# IdentityServer 4: Are Scopes unique to the ApiResource?

Tags: identityserver4, scopes

Is there a restriction in IdentityServer that scopes can only belong to a single ApiResource?

It seems to me that IdentityServer builds a list of audiences using the list of allowed scopes to look up the ApiResources they belong to, and that each scope only belongs to a single ApiResource.

We have defined the following set of ApiResources and their scopes:

```
ApiResource     Scopes
------------------------------
api/Orders      api/Orders
api/Products    api/Producs
```

Which produeces a nice set of aud(ience) and scope values in our JWT:

```
aud:
api/Orders
api/Products

scope:
api/Orders
api/Products
```

However, when we made the mistake of messing up the configuration by reusing the same scope for both ApiResources, things got a bit weird:

```
ApiResource     Scopes
------------------------------
api/Orders      api/Products
api/Products    api/Products
```

We ended up with this:

```
aud:
api/Orders

scope:
api/Products
```

It seems that the way the list of audiences is built up is by calling `IResourceStore.GetAllResources()` (which we have implemented to retrieve the full catalog of ApiResources and their associated scopes), and then grabs the first ApiResource that matches a given allowed scope, which should work just fine as long as no other ApiResources also have the same scope. :)

-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope names must be unique.

If you want to use the same scope names in several APIs - prefix them e.g. "api1.read", "api2.read" or similar.

Comment: Thanks! We're changing our configuration structure to avoid duplication of scopes.